# Yii pagination is not working

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using CListWiev but when I click on particular link to page, it won`t be reload to page. In my browser I checked that some response is coming back to site, but it does nothing. Everything worked well on localhost, but when I put my project on server, it caused this failure. Could somebody help me?

**controller**

```
    class SiteController extends Controller {

        public function renderVideos($action, $order, $title, $isIndex) {
            $join = ' JOIN page_has_video on page_has_video.video_id = t.id
                              JOIN page on page_has_video.page_id = page.id';
            $criteria = $this->getCriteria($join);
            $criteria->order = $order;

            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Video', array
                (
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10),
            ));

            $this->render($action, array('videos' => $videos, 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'index' => $isIndex, 'title' => $title));
        }

        public function actionIndex() {
            $this->renderVideos('index', 't.id desc', 'New', true);
        }

    }
    ?>
```

**_vidSubsection.php**

```
    <?php
    $lw = $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_video',
        'pager' => array(
            'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/clistview.css',
            'header' => false,
            'firstPageLabel' => '<<',
            'prevPageLabel' => '<',
            'nextPageLabel' => '>',
            'lastPageLabel' => '>>',
        ),
        'summaryText' => '',
        'sortableAttributes' => array(
        ),
            ));
    ?>
    </ul>
```

**_video.php**

```
    <li class = 'videoItem'>

        <div class="videoSeen">
            <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>
                 /images/eye.png"  alt="videne" title="Seen" class="seenImage" />
            <span class="seenValue">
    <?php
    $seen = $data->seen;
    if ($seen == NULL) {
        $seen = 0;
    }
    echo $seen;
    ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: do you see any javascript errors on console? are you using mod_rewrite? is everything else working?

Comment: I am using htaccess and also mod_rewrite in it. I checked, that some request is coming to server and also some response to browser. And this response is page which I want to be shown. And when I put this URL to the browser it caused nothing even though in there is another situation on localhost. On localhost it returns URL which works well. I don`t know, what is wrong at all.

Comment: if you are getting a blank page, then you may be having a PHP Error, check your apache error log.

Comment: I am not getting a blank page. Browser do nothing, when I am clicking on next page in pagination, nothing happens.

Comment: sounds like javascript events not getting attached.

Comment: I finaly find out that it was problem of one parameter in main.php config file. I commented out line  urlFormat'=>'path' and it works. Thank you.